# How to statically link allegro5 (Linux, G++)?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, static-linking, allegro5

I built the latest stable version of allegro5's source code following [these steps](http://curtis.schlak.com/2014/05/22/creating-and-using-allegro-5-static-libraries-with-xcode-5.html)

I have the following code (main.cpp):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>

int main()
{
    al_init();
    al_install_keyboard();
    al_install_mouse();
    al_init_primitives_addon();
    al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_RESIZABLE);
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display = al_create_display(1280, 720);
    al_set_window_title(display, "Allegro5 Window");
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE* queue = al_create_event_queue();
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());

    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT ev;
        while (al_get_next_event(queue, &ev))
        {
            if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE)
                running = false;
            if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_RESIZE)
            {
                al_acknowledge_resize(display);
            }
        }

        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgba_f(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 1));
        al_flip_display();
    }

    al_destroy_event_queue(queue);
    al_destroy_display(display);

    return 0;
}
```

... And I am trying to build this source file using the following command:

```
g++ -g $(pkg-config --libs --static allegro-static-5 allegro_primitives-static-5) main.cpp -o main
```

Even though pkg-config detects everything, it still doesn't work. The output is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmxycjk.o: in function `main':
pwd/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `al_install_system'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `al_install_keyboard'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `al_install_mouse'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `al_init_primitives_addon'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `al_set_new_display_flags'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `al_create_display'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `al_set_window_title'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `al_create_event_queue'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `al_get_display_event_source'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `al_register_event_source'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `al_get_keyboard_event_source'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `al_register_event_source'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `al_get_mouse_event_source'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `al_register_event_source'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `al_get_next_event'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `al_acknowledge_resize'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `al_map_rgba_f'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `al_clear_to_color'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `al_flip_display'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:37: undefined reference to `al_destroy_event_queue'
/usr/bin/ld: pwd/main.cpp:38: undefined reference to `al_destroy_display'
```

OBS: PWD = project path. Running up-to-date Debian 10

I've tried compiling with '-l:', adding all the libs, etc. Nothing would work. Any ideas?

Comment: I could only get it to work with dynamic linking... I still have no answer for the question itself, but this is what I'm using to compile it dynamically:
g++ -g $(pkg-config --libs pangocairo atk gdk-pixbuf-2.0 pangoft2 pango opus libpulse-simple libpulse openal  allegro_color-5 allegro_dialog-5 allegro-5 allegro_main-5 allegro_memfile-5 allegro_acodec-5 allegro_font-5 allegro_video-5 allegro_audio-5 allegro_primitives-5 allegro_ttf-5 allegro_physfs-5 allegro_image-5) main.cpp -o main

Comment: Did you check the official FAQ regarding to static linking? https://github.com/liballeg/allegro_wiki/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-statically-link It says "**Sacrifice a virgin maiden to the gods of Mt Allegrohorn.**" :D

Answer (score 0):

Before you `#include <allegro5/...>`, add:

```
#define ALLEGRO_STATICLINK
```

You may need to link with additional libraries used by Allegro as well, such as OpenGL32.lib (on Windows), to resolve OpenGL functions.